# Can a higher wattage solar panel in series pick up slack for lower wattage panels?

Tags: solar-energy

I have (in series) three 100 W panels and one 175 W panel. The 100 W panels (with bypass diode) are rated at just under 5 amps, and the 175 W panel is rated at 9 amps. From what I have read this means my 175 W panel will be limited to 5 amps.

I’m aware chaining these is not recommended due to the difference in amps (was not aware of that prior to ordering the 175 W panel).

My question is - if the three 100 W panels are not at full output for whatever reason (such as sun behind clouds or a situation where the 100 W panels are shaded but not the 175 W panel), does this allow the 175 W panel to output more than 5 amps to make up for the fact the other panels aren’t producing their maximum output - or is it just always stuck at 5 amps or less by being connected to the lower amperage panels?

Comment: How are these connected: each panel has a bypass diode, then is wired to what?

Comment: They are wired in series and connected to a charge controller / 400ah battery bank. I don’t think the 175w panel has a bypass diode, just the 100w panels.

Comment: What is the battery voltage, and which controller are you using?

Comment: Renogy 40a MPPT. The battery bank is 12v consists of 2 12v 200ah batteries in parallel.